# SpringBoot 1.5.x to 2.x upgrade

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, netflix-eureka

I am looking at the migration guide in this link

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide

Our environment currently has SpringBoot Services running 1.5.x. I am planning an upgrade to 2.x but would prefer planning for it a Service at a time at least to start with. We use Discovery (eureka), Config and other Spring Cloud modules as well.

I am planning to start with Discovery and wanted to get advice on how people have gone ahead with a migration as such. So based this plan, discovery will run 2.x with clients running 1.x to start.

Comment: I'd recommend you start with Config service  or Discovery service that you won't have issues on them but if you are working with gradle and you were using. 2.x.  version so you need to upgrade to 4.x, also if you are working in production you need to take in account. Where you are going to need more work, it will be on domain services which using JPA and more on security service. This will depend on complexity of your project.

Comment: Thanks. In your experience, have you encountered any issues with Clients with 1.5.x and Discovery/Config on 2.x?

Comment: None but if you are sharing dependencies on root of a microservices project so you need to update all that is being shared, in addition you also have to update spring cloud dependencies if you are using it. Here is the link   https://spring.io/blog/2018/06/19/spring-cloud-finchley-release-is-available

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Our Services are isolated having their own repos. I will start with Discovery and Config and see how it goes.

Comment: @tapitoe how did it go?

Comment: @Abhi We went with upgrading the Services first and then finally upgraded Eureka Discovery.